# Pandas: Merge many-to-one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, many-to-one

Let's say I have 2 data frames:

`df1`:

```
Name  Age
Pete  19
John  30
Max   24
```

`df2`:

```
Name   Subject  Grade  
Pete   Math     90
Pete   History  100
John   English  90
Max    History  90
Max    Math     80
```

I want to merge them `df2` to `df1`, many to one, to end up with something like this:

```
Name   Age  Subject  Grade  
Pete   19   Math     90
Pete   19   History  100
John   30   English  90
Max    24   History  90
Max    24   Math     80
```

I don't want to group them by `Subject` and `Grade`, I need to duplicate them so it would keep everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you could use `pd.merge` as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
if __name__ == '__main__':
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Name": ["Pete", "John", "Max"],
                        "Age": [19, 30, 24]})
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Name": ["Pete", "Pete", "John", "Max", "Max"],
                        "Subject": ["Math", "History", "English", "History", "Math"],
                        "Grade": [90, 100, 90, 90, 80]})
    df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how="right", on="Name")
    print(df1)
    print(df2)
    print(df3)
```

Result:

```
   Name  Age
0  Pete   19
1  John   30
2   Max   24
   Name  Subject  Grade
0  Pete     Math     90
1  Pete  History    100
2  John  English     90
3   Max  History     90
4   Max     Math     80
   Name  Age  Subject  Grade
0  Pete   19     Math     90
1  Pete   19  History    100
2  John   30  English     90
3   Max   24  History     90
4   Max   24     Math     80
```